# Why does it throws DirectoryNotFoundException even though Directory.Exists returns true?

Tags: c#, file-io, directory, filesystems, console-application

So I'm making a really small console application that organizes some directories, because I want to know at least some basic things on how to treat files and directories on C#, for this I used `Directory.Move`, like this:

```cs
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "/";
try
{
 string subDirectoryPath = Path.GetFullPath(subDirectoryName);
 string newCompletePath = Path.GetFullPath(newPath);
 if (Directory.Exists(subDirectoryPath) && !Directory.Exists(newCompletePath))
 {
  Directory.Move(subDirectoryPath, Path.GetFullPath(newPath));
  SuccessMessage("{0}: -> {1}", subDirectoryName, newPath);
 }
 ErrorMessage($"The path `{subDirectoryPath}` doesn't exists!");
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
{
 ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
 ErrorMessage(ex.StackTrace);
 Errors.Add($"ERROR ON: {subDirectoryName}");
}
```

The strange thing happens when it reaches de `if` statement, it returns true but when it reaches the `Directory.Move` function it throws a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. The variable `subDirectoryName` is one of the strings obtained via `Directory.GetDirectories`. I even tried using `DirectoryInfo` like this:

```cs
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "/";
try
{
 DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subDirectoryName);
 directoryInfo.MoveTo(newPath);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
{
 ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
 ErrorMessage(ex.StackTrace);
 Errors.Add($"ERROR ON: {subDirectoryName}");
}
```

But still, no success, and the thrown exception remains the same.

I'm on a Mac, using Visual Studio for Mac, there isn't anything running asynchronously that could affect that path, and the GoTo shortcut on Finder works wonderfully with the value of `subDirectoryPath`.

I suspect it has something to do with the names of the directories, because they can have some strange characters, for example this is one of them:
`/Users/elrohir/Downloads/Comics/[Gokusaishiki (Aya Shachou)] Chikokuma Renko 2 ~Fukushuu no Chikokusha~` (the strange characters being ~). And I tried using much simpler names like: `/Users/elrohir/Downloads/Comics/Comic Name 1` and it works perfectly there. Any ideas on how to solve this or what is causing it?

Comment: Can you show the error with exact directory paths that causes an exception?

Comment: You do not have the credetials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! using this code from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netcore-3.1) instead (still don't know why it didn't worked before though).

```cs
Environment.CurrentDirectory = "/";
 try
 {
   DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subDirectoryName);

   if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
   {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
   }

   foreach(FileInfo image in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
   {
     image.CopyTo(Path.Combine(newPath, image.Name), true);
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
     Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", newPath, image.Name);
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
   }
     SuccessMessage("{0}: -> {1}", subDirectoryName, newPath);
 }
 catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
 {
   ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
   ErrorMessage(ex.StackTrace);
   Errors.Add($"ERROR ON: {subDirectoryName}");
 }
```

Now all images/files inside `subDirectoryName` get copied to the `newPath`.